# How can I get rounded minutes directly in strtotime

Tags: php, strtotime

I want to get the next rounded hour (10:00:00 instead of 10:25:01) by calling the `strtotime` function. The output from `strtotime` should translate directly to the rounded hour.

At the moment if I do

```
var_dump(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1 hour')));
```

I get an unrounded value such as

```
string '2011-08-16 10:21:57' (length=19)
```

while I would like to get

```
string '2011-08-16 10:00:00' (length=19)
```

I know this can be achieved by doing:

```
var_dump(date('Y-m-d H:00:00', strtotime('+1 hour')));
```

But I'd like to achieve the same by using strtotime only. So I need a string that will evaluate to the rounded hour by strtotime.

I tried values such as

```
next hour, 0 minutes
+1 hour, 0 minutes
next rounded hour
```

but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [PHP's relative format docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php), there's no `strtotime` argument for this purpose.